# Creating a generalized HTTP Authentication function

Tags: php, xml, basic-authentication

I am using the script below to login to get the xml data.  Is there away that I can use the same login script but change the `$oPMainUrl` when required?

**HTTPS URI:** `https://domain.co.nz/file.xml`

**Current API Login:**

```
$oPMainUrl = 'HTTPS URI';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $oPMainUrl);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:pw");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$MainURI = simplexml_load_string($result);

$ID = $MainURI->property->agency_id;
```

Comment: @Rob I have tried concatenating the strings onto the result etc but of course I get not authenticated.  The oPMain url shows one lot of info but then I need to pass another so I am unsure

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Do you mean to say that simply setting `$oPMainURL = 'https://domain.co.nz/file.xml?xmlFunction=Value';` does not work? HTTP basic authentication should not stop you from passing query parameters

Comment: @Phil Please have a look at my example that I have just posted,  I need the `$oPMainURL` to stay the same as this has the ID that is feed into the new "function" that I am creating.

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Sorry, I'm not following you. In any case, HTTP basic auth is dead simple. You just need to add the credentials to every request. There is no session, each request requires authentication

Comment: @Phil Ahh that answers my question  I need to redo it for every request.  Thanks Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP basic auth is dead simple. You just need to add the credentials to every request. There is no session, each request requires authentication.