# Gaining access to a certain XML area

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the below XML Structure below but I am unsure how I can get direct access to the URL so that I can use it as a `src` in my image tag.

**PHP Structure:**

```
$images = $url->property->photos
<img src="'.$images.'" width="233" height="154" /> - Testing URL
```

**General XML Structure:**

```
<photos>
 <photo>
  Information
 </photo>
</photos>
```

**XML Structure:**

```
["photos"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#118 (2) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["count"]=>
        string(2) "43"
      }
      ["photo"]=>
      array(43) {
        [0]=>
        string(97) "http://www.domain.co.nz/images/6f8bc4855bface1ad2c35635625fdbb4c3a11537.jpeg"
        [1]=>
        string(97) "http://www.domain.co.nz/images/fcb36e4a3465b934490d44e6bb8e1a8192cb466d.jpeg"
        [2]=>
        string(97) "http://www.domain.co.nz/images//c1e2c792832a08f881bb24756137a63a19c7070d.jpeg"
        [3]=>
        string(97) "http://www.domain.co.nz/images/b6d9a3c52c7fba81553edb9101c80d273c16ee3c.jpeg"
```

Comment: The XMLblock says `photo` but the url object says `photos`.  issue?

Comment: @Smandoli I have now included a general xml structure.  If I `var_dump` `$images` I get the "XML Structure"

Comment: Basic Trouble Shooting:  For example, if you paste one of the image URLs into the PHP, does it show?  (If not, maybe inconsistent quote marks are a problem.)

Comment: @Smandoli Yes I have and it does show,  Where have I gone wrong with my quote marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<properties count="1">
        <property approved="yesterday">
                <address>123 Main Street</address>
                <photos count="2">
                        <photo>1.jpg</photo>
                        <photo>2.jpg</photo>
                </photos>
        </property>
</properties>
XML;
$properties = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);//this could have been done using simplexml_load_file($url); for instance
//the important part is that you have a SimpleXML object named $properties
foreach($properties->property as $property){
        echo $property['approved']."<br>\n";
        echo $property->address."<br>\n";
        foreach($property->photos->photo as $photo){
                echo $photo."<br>\n";
        }
}
```

I assume you may have multiple properties and you want to list each one. If you only have one, or only want to list the first one, you can safely remove the first foreach loop:

```
echo $properties->property[0]['approved']."<br>\n";
echo $properties->property[0]->address."<br>\n";
foreach($properties->property[0]->photos->photo as $photo){
    echo $photo."<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  Would $xmlstr = my main url? - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132106/http-authentication-creating-a-generalized-authentication

Comment: No, in this case I'm just putting the XML text directly into my php script. I assume you're getting it from another server?

Comment: If you are getting it from a url: where I say $properties = new SimpleXML($xmlstr)....you should do $properties = simplexml_load_file($your_url); You can delete the $xmlstr to XML; portion.

Comment: Ok that would be $MainURI = simplexml_load_string($result); as I cannot use load_file due to needing authentication

Comment: I think you could simply put $result into my line: $properties = new SimpleXML($result);//assuming $result is literally XML **text**

Answer (score 0):

If you var_dump'd like this:

```
var_dump($images);
//output:
object(SimpleXMLElement)#117 (2) {...
```

You can access those photo URLs in a loop like so:

```
foreach($images->photo as $image){
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'"/>;
}
```

Comment: Hey,  I have looked over the var again and noted that it was #118 not #117 I have updated the question.  I also tried the above and I got nothing its the `property->photo;` that holds the info

Comment: The #117 is irrelevant. For our purposes, consider that a random number.

Comment: I don't see any <property> tags anywhere in your question.

Comment: $images = $url->property->photos['photos']; may work. Your XML and naming conventions are confusing along with not seeing the full XML or how it was set.

Comment: My naming conventions are just for this post.  Here is a print out of the full XML http://dev.jzm.co.nz/stack/fullXML.pdf